# legacy jquery datatables sort on Australian date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datatable, datatables

According to the [jQuery Datatables docs](https://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns), the `sType` parameter which is used to define the sorting behaviour of a column:

> ... allows you to specify how the data for this column will be
> sorted. Four types (string, numeric, date and html (which will strip
> HTML tags before sorting)) are currently available. Note that only
> date formats understood by Javascript's Date() object will be accepted
> as type date. For example: "Mar 26, 2008 5:03 PM". May take the
> values: 'string', 'numeric', 'date' or 'html' (by default). Further
> types can be adding through plug-ins.

However, when values in the columns are of the format dd/MMM/yyyy (eg `<td>08/Mar/2024</td>`), the column does not sort properly.

Javascript definitely understands `08/Mar/2024` as being a valid date:

```
new Date("08/Mar/2024");
Fri Mar 08 2024 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)
```

So what exactly can i do to sort it using Australian date format?

Comment: There is a section in the official documentation which focuses on [date and time handling](https://datatables.net/examples/datetime/index.html) examples. Note the two examples there which specifically address date sorting. Do any of these help you?

Comment: I understand that the question mentions "legacy" - so, if you are using an older (legacy) version of DataTables, can you clarify what version you are using (again, a [mre] is typically the best way to do that).

Comment: There are also many (many!) existing questions and solutions on Stack Overflow for date sorting in DataTables, using custom date formats - maybe one of those meets your needs?

Comment: Add `data-sort='20240308'` https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data#HTML-5  Whether that's available in your "legacy" version is anyone's guess until you tell us the version - but it's been an option since v1.10

Comment: "*Javascript definitely understands 08/Mar/2024 as being a valid date:*" No it does not. Three formats are supported by ECMA-262, "08/Mar/2024" is not one of them so parsing is implementation dependent. Safari at least considers it an invalid date, though Firefox doesn't.